# New code changes exist in live container but are not reflected in the browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, apache-superset

I am using Docker with the open source BI tool [Apache Superset](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#start-with-docker).  I have added a new file, specifically a .geojson file in the CountryMap directory. Now, when I try to build using `docker-compose up --build` or make changes in the frontend, Docker is not fully updated, and I get a file not found error when trying to run a query. When I look inside the container via `docker exec -it container_id bash`, the new file is there.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.6-jessie

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --no-log-init --shell /bin/bash superset

# Configure environment
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -y

# Install dependencies to fix `curl https support error` and `elaying package configuration warning`
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https apt-utils

# Install superset dependencies
# https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#os-dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev \
    libffi-dev python3-dev libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libxi-dev

# Install extra useful tool for development
RUN apt-get install -y vim less postgresql-client redis-tools

# Install nodejs for custom build
# https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#making-your-own-build
# https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs

WORKDIR /home/superset

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY requirements-dev.txt .
COPY contrib/docker/requirements-extra.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt -r requirements-extra.txt \
    && rm -rf /root/.cache/pip

RUN pip install gevent

COPY --chown=superset:superset superset superset

ENV PATH=/home/superset/superset/bin:$PATH \
    PYTHONPATH=/home/superset/superset/:$PYTHONPATH

USER superset

RUN cd superset/assets \
    && npm ci \
    && npm run build \
    && rm -rf node_modules

COPY contrib/docker/docker-init.sh .
COPY contrib/docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

HEALTHCHECK CMD ["curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8088/health"]

EXPOSE 8088
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: superset
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: superset
      POSTGRES_USER: superset
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  superset:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: contrib/docker/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: superset
      POSTGRES_USER: superset
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: superset
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      # If using production, comment development volume below
      #SUPERSET_ENV: production
      SUPERSET_ENV: development
#      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    user: root:root
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      # this is needed to communicate with the postgres and redis services
      - ./superset_config.py:/home/superset/superset/superset_config.py
      # this is needed for development, remove with SUPERSET_ENV=production
      - ../../superset:/home/superset/superset

volumes:
  postgres:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

Why is there a not found error?

Comment: your map volume will overide any new thing in the image

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? (note minimal = we shouldn't need to install >50MB, complete = not depending on files that aren't included in your question, and reproducible = we can run this on our own machines)

Comment: @Adiii I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Do you mean that it doesn't matter if I add a new file to the Maps directory, because in the end the volume will stay the same?

Comment: if you build your image any time, but it will only pick the mapped volume data. try to remove volume and you see will thing from updated image.

Comment: @BMitch unfortunately I don't think I can compress the problem into a minimalistic one with 1 .py and 1 .js file that you can run on your machine, since many files are interconnected

Comment: @Adiii i removed the volumes(`docker-compose down --volumes`) and ran the container again, but the file is still not found

Comment: try: `docker-compose build --no-cache `

Comment: @LinPy I have, still no change

Comment: Ok, this is extreme, but could you try docker-compose up --build --force-recreate? Are you adding the file through superset frontend? You can execute shell on the container (docker exec -it containerid bash) and see if the file is present where its supposed to be found.

Comment: @Jayachandran no change occurs with adding `--force-recreate` flag either. The file is located in the correct directory in the superset container

Comment: Which means it might not be a docker issue. May be explore superset cache settings - I am not very familiar with superset, so can't help you there.

Comment: When you build docker image, are those docker instructions are executing.

Comment: @Keaz yes they are

Comment: @Jayachandran when I install superset via source I don't face this issue. That's why I'm thinking this is a Docker issue. Also, when I `cd` inside the container I can see the updated files, but this is not reflected on the browser

Answer (score 0):

try to use absolute path in `volumes:`

```
volumes:
  - /home/me/my_project/superset_config.py:/home/superset/superset/superset_config.py
  - /home/me/my_project/superset:/home/superset/superset
```

Comment: what difference does changing the path make?

Comment: With absolute path it will map existing folder, with relative docker will create empty volume

Comment: Well as far as I know this is not the case. As the documentation says: `You can mount a relative path on the host, which expands relative to the directory of the Compose configuration file being used. Relative paths should always begin with . or ...` and besides that you will loose your portability as other users will have to create the same users etc...

Comment: Nothing changed with switching to absolute path

Answer (score 0):

It is because `docker-compose` is utilizing **cache**. If the `dockerfile` and the `docker-compose.yml` in not changed it does not recreate the container image. To avoid this you should use the following flag:

```
 --force-recreate
```

> --force-recreate
>
> Recreate containers even if their configuration and image haven't
>   changed.

For development purposes I like to use the following switch as well:

> -V, --renew-anon-volumes
>
> Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving data from the previous containers.

Comment: I get the same result when using the `force-recreate` flag. I mentioned it in a comment of the question

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more where the `CountryMap` directory? How did you add the mentioned file?

Comment: Hi, the directory is located in the visualizations folder `superset/assets/src/visualizations/CountryMap/countries`. I added the map by following these steps: https://superset.incubator.apache.org/visualization.html#need-to-add-a-new-country

Comment: when installing superset from source, I can see and interact with the map, but with Docker I get the not found error

Comment: Hmmm your build context is `context: ../../` and your volume is  `../../superset:/home/superset/superset` are you sure that you need these: `../../`?

Comment: I think so, because if I remove it then the volume superset:/home/superset/superset won't be found when starting the service

Comment: Although you might be right that the superset volume could be the issue. When I `docker volume ls` I only see the postgres and redis volumes, not the superset one

Comment: Could you elaborate on this comment as well? `# this is needed for development, remove with SUPERSET_ENV=production`

Comment: The superset volume is not used when in production. And commands like npm ci and npm run dev are not executed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200525/discussion-between-mark-and-snow).